# Modules loaded according apache2ctl vs plesk?

Tags: apache-2.2

When i list loaded modules by apache2ctl i get the list:

```
#apache2ctl -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

However, when i open plesk on same server, i get planty of modules and 21 various modules marked as loaded.

What i'm seeing wrong?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache2ctl -l only lists modules compiled in to the daemon, it does not list shared modules. In order to see these too use the following command:

```
apache2ctl -M
```